# Combining ons-navigator and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I am trying to create an `ons-navigator` element with an arbitrary number of pages based on an array using `ng-repeat` or something similar. Within this I need to find a way to skip forwards through the pages.

I have tried using `ng-repeat` on `ons-template` within my navigator to no avail. There is a GitHub issue explaining why my approach doesn't work: https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/issues/233

Answer (score 0):

Currently you can just put any number of pages in the navigator from the start.

```
<ons-navigator>
  <ons-page ng-repeat="page in pages">{{$index}}</ons-page>
</ons-navigator>
```

This works fine. Now about the `skipping forward` part - actually the navigator is supposed to have pages inside as if they were a stack, meaning that the last page is supposed to always be the visible one. That's why it also has methods `pushPage` and `popPage`. So what you should generally do is just push only the pages which you want in your stack. So in your case the `$scope.pages` should have only the pages which you need. If you have pages which you need in the future it's best if you add them later.

Still if you want to put more pages than the ones you will need you can still do that but then you'll need to manage the showing of the pages by yourself. Your two options would then be:

- To hide the pages which you don't want.
- To use something like `bringPageTop` to put the ones which you want on the top of the stack.

Here's a [Demo](http://codepen.io/IliaSky/pen/wGRNQz?editors=1010) of these two approaches.

And about generating dynamic templates - maybe you could try to manage by using one template, but having it's controller do whatever you want. Initially you cannot use something like `ng-repeat` on the template itself but after you add the template contents to the dom then the bindings will work fine. In that case you can just push the same template multiple times (without animation probably) and just change whatever you want in the scope.